# How do I append the data in text files and combine multiple text files into one text file using python?

Tags: python, pandas

> My file is like this
> Heading1, Heading2, Heading3, Heading4, Heading5
>
> Alpha, Beta, Gama, Face, Human
>
> Dog, Camel, Horse, Lion
>
> ################# Summary ###############################
>
> ```
> Heading6 = V8CA02TB
> Heading7 = 8R1
> Heading8 = ENVS2F12SLB2
> Heading9 = mkern2
> Heading10 = 1654774930624
> Heading11 =  09 13:42:10 2022
> ```

I want to make file like this

> Heading1, Heading2, Heading3, Heading4, Heading5, Heading6, Heading7,
> Heading8, Heading9, Heading10, Heading11
>
> Alpha, Beta, Gama, Face, Human, V8CA02TB, 8R1, ENVS2F12SLB2, mkern2,
> 1654774930624, 09 13:42:10 2022
>
> Cat, Dog, Camel, Horse, Lion, V8CA02TB, 8R1, ENVS2F12SLB2,
> mkern2, 1654774930624, 09 13:42:10 2022

I have to do that on multiple files and then combine all the files in one text file

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's not hard, just tedious.  You'll need to read the file into a list of lists (or list of dicts) until you get to the summary.  Then you grab the fields of the summary, and then you combine them.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what any of this is supposed to mean. Please read [ask] and [mre] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and make sure to **ask a question**, starting with a question word like "why" or "how" and ending with a question mark (`?`). "Any help will be appreciated" [does not qualify](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236), and "Thanks in advance" is [unnecessary and unwanted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) regardless of spelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will parse your format.

```
with open('x.data') as fin:
    header = None
    rows = []
    extra = []

    for line in fin:
        if len(line) < 5:
            continue
        if not header:
            header = line.strip().split(',')
        elif 'Summary' in line:
            break
        else:
            rows.append( line.strip().split(',') )
        
    for line in fin:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        left,_,right = line.partition(' = ')
        header.append( left )
        extra.append( right )

with open('out.data', 'w') as fout:
    print( ','.join(header), file=fout )
    for row in rows:
        print( ','.join(row+extra), file=fout )
```

Output:

```
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K
Alpha, Beta, Gama, Face, Human,V8CA02TB,8R1,ENVS2F12SLB2,mkern2,1654774930624, 09 13:42:10 2022
Cat, Dog, Camel, Horse, Lion,V8CA02TB,8R1,ENVS2F12SLB2,mkern2,1654774930624, 09 13:42:10 2022
```

Combining multiple files is easy, even without Python.